How can I load (gensim) data from local machine behind firewall?
I am trying to use gensim. I need to load the data, but I am behind firewall. So, I get error while I tried the default code.
import gensim
import gensim.downloader as api
dataset = api.load("text8")
data = [i for i in dataset]

Now I have two questions,

Where can I find the data (e.g., text8 for gensim)?
How do I load that from local folder?

Thank you.

What error do you get?
